# Where there is no data printed in this sql command query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable

#### Purpose

I want to print all the rows in my database table `Orders` where the `PrintTime` field value is `NULL`

#### Code

```
class Printing
{
    public static void check() 
    {
        SqlConnection con = getConnectionString();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE PrintTime = @printTimeValue";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@printTimeValue", DBNull.Value);
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        using (con)
        using (command)
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            dataAdapter.Fill(results);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(results.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        }
    }
    private static SqlConnection getConnectionString()
    {           
        string vmpstring = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chinese"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection vmpsqlcon = new SqlConnection(vmpstring);
        return vmpsqlcon;
    }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
Printing.check();
```

#### Problem

As you see, there is a printing statement, which is

```
Console.WriteLine(results.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
```

but I don't get any thing printed in the console, though I can see the rows in my database, full of data that its `PrintTime`column is `NULL`

#### Question

what wrong did I do please?

Comment: put `PrintTime = @printTimeValue` where `@printTimeValue` is `NULL` is *provoking* a server: according ANSI SQL 92 the condition is NULL, even if MS SQL has a setting that allows treat as `IS NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`null` is not a value but a marker stating that the rdbms has no clue of the value in that field; you cannot check for `null` using '=' because the equals operator is for values.

in your sql you have to check for null using `WHERE PrintTime is null`.

beware that if you replace the c# `DBNull.Value` with an actual value then the 'is' operator is not valid anymore.

a possible workaround that can handle both null and values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Orders 
WHERE  PrintTime = @printTimeValue
       or (
         @printTimeValue is null 
         and PrintTime is null
       )
```